# Getting the error "Unknown receiver coachMarksView; Did you mean WSCoachMarksView error?"

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm currently implementing the [WSCoachMarksView](https://github.com/workshirt/WSCoachMarksView) framework to introduce users to features when using the app for the first time. The code in my `viewDidAppear` however, gives me the following error: `Unknown receiver 'coachMarksView'; Did you mean 'WSCoachMarksView'?`

I'm not sure why this is happening, since I've instantiated `coachMarksView` already in `viewDidLoad`, so it should recognize it. Am I missing something?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Setup coach marks
    NSArray *coachMarks = @[
                            @{
                                @"rect": [NSValue valueWithCGRect:(CGRect){{50,168},{220,45}}],
                                @"caption": @"Just browsing? We'll only notify you periodically of new matches. Need it soon? We'll notify you more frequently, and match you with items that are closer to you."
                                },
                            ];

    WSCoachMarksView *coachMarksView = [[WSCoachMarksView alloc] initWithFrame:self.navigationController.view.bounds coachMarks:coachMarks];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:coachMarksView];
    coachMarksView.animationDuration = 0.5f;
    coachMarksView.enableContinueLabel = YES;
    [coachMarksView start];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    // Show coach marks
    BOOL coachMarksShown = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"WSCoachMarksShown"];
    if (coachMarksShown == NO) {
        // Don't show again
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"WSCoachMarksShown"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        // Show coach marks
        [coachMarksView start];

        // Or show coach marks after a second delay
        // [coachMarksView performSelector:@selector(start) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f];
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make coachMarksView a property so you can access the same instance. coachMarksView is undefined in viewWillAppear: because that scope has no knowledge of the scope in viewDidLoad.

To create a property for coachMarksView you need to do the following in your viewController:

```
@interface UIViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) WKCoachMarksView *coachMarksView;
@end
```

and then in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  self.coachMarksView = [[WSCoachMarksView alloc] initWithFrame:self.navigationController.bounds]];
}
```

Now to access that instance just use self.coachMarksView.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  [self.coachMarksView start];
}
```

Here is more info on getters, setters, and properties in Objective-C http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/properties.html

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `coachMarksView` as a local variable inside `viewDidLoad`.  "Local" means it's only visible where you declared it.

Try changing it to a property of the class instead so that your object can access it from all of its methods.  (Using `self.coachMarksView`.)

Comment: Ah makes sense. I've tried doing it like so: `WSCoachMarksView *self.coachMarksView = [[WSCoachMarksView alloc] initWithFrame:self.navigationController.view.bounds coachMarks:coachMarks];` but it's giving me an error. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: Here's a syntax reference for properties: https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html

Answer (score 0):

Post out my case, maybe useful for somebody:

- **Error**：`Unknown receiver 'RSJsonSymbol'; did you mean 'RSSymbol'? Replace 'RSJsonSymbol' with 'RSSymbol'`
- **Reason**: not include header file
- **Solution**: include its header file `RSJsonSymbol.h`